# find the joining date and month in between a range of date

Tags: excel, date

I want to find the joining date and month in between a range of date eg. i want to find  only the joining date and month in any given year, if yes then add 20 and if no then the result will be 0. 
eg.

```
A1          B1           C1                         D1(result)
20/03/2016  20/03/2016   24/04/1990(Dt.of joining)  0
10/04/2016  25/04/2016   24/04/1990(Dt.of joining)  20
```

Answer in a formula will be very helpful.

Comment: Thanks Florent, your solution just worked marvelously. I had been searching for this solution on the net for a long time.

Comment: Thanks Florent, your solution just worked marvelously.  But there is one problem I face. If the range of date falls in the previous year then it shows 20. eg.If I show the date range from A!: 25/04/2015  B1: 20/02/2016  C1: 24/04/1990 (DOJ), it shows 20 instead of 0, since 20 should be added in between the date range which appears on 24th April of any year. Thanks for any solution given Your formula: =SUMPRODUCT((MEDIAN(DATE(YEAR(C1),MONTH(A1),DAY(A1)),DATE(YEAR(C1),MONTH(B1),DAY(B1)),C1)=C1)*20)

Comment: would appreciate to have a modified formula which will also include the flow of date from one year to another year say for eg. August 2015 to February 2016 (an individual joining the service on 24th August 2015 will complete his one year on 23rd August 2016).

Answer (score 1):

Use this in D1 and copy down as needed:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((MEDIAN(DATE(YEAR(C1),MONTH(A1),DAY(A1)),DATE(YEAR(C1),MONTH(B1),DAY(B1)),C1)=C1)*20)
```

[image]

Comment: Why do you need the `year`?

Comment: I needed three dates all on the same year to use the MEDIAN() formula.  So I did not need to do a DATE() function for the third I decided to use the year from the test date. @findwindow

Comment: I need the year since once in a year I need to add 20 Half Pay Leave in the account of an employee and that will be added on the anniversary of the joining date of the employee i.e. on completion of one year in service (hear it will be 24th April of every year).